# the OKCupid formula (and other ways of estimating similarity with limited data)

Tags: machine-learning, similarities

Say I have a test, that receives a string and returns either Belongs or Does Not Belong (to a set)

I know the true answers (if each sample belongs to the set or not), and I want to evaluate the quality of the test.

Specifically, I want to evaluate its precision: when it answers "Belongs", what percentage of the time is the test correct?

However, for some tests I have few samples (say, only 6 strings such that the test returned "Belongs"). I could just say that its precision is the frequency of correct answers, but I would prefer a formula that could also take into account the size of the sample

I mention OKCupid because I remember having read, a while ago, that they used to do this: apply some formula to decrease the match percentage of people if there were insufficient samples to create a good estimate. I mean to do something similar: I prefer to consider a rule that has too few samples bad, rather than good.

What are some techniques for that?